# How to store value into different activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

In my android application, there's an EditText for name in MainActivity and I want to send user's input into 2 different activity. How to do that ?

It's my sample code in MainActivity :

```
EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String sName = Name.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),firstActivity.class);
i.putExtra("sName", sName);
startActivity(i);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("sName", sName);
```

It's my sample code in firstActivity :

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String name = getStringExtra("sName");
```

Sample code in secondActivity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = getStringExtra("sName");
```

Getting input in firstActivity, but not in secondActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to share or send values to your all activities then use SharedPreference

Activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("key", sName);
editor.commit();
```

SecondActivity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String email = sharedPref.getString(keyString, defaultValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access one value to other classes/Activity/Fragments.

Put into one class and access from other classes.

```
 public static String getsName(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = null;
    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("APPNAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getString("sName", "");
}

public static void setsName(Context context, String Data) {
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor lock_editor;

    pref = context.getSharedPreferences("APPNAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    lock_editor = pref.edit();
    lock_editor.putString("sName", Data);
    lock_editor.commit();
}
```